# How do I find the limits of integration for a triple integral over a given region?

Tags: integration

If I'm given that $U = \{(x, y, z): x+y \leq  z \leq 4−x−y,  x \geq 0,  y  \geq 0\}$. How do I find the limits of integration for 
$$
 \iiint_U x \,dV ?
$$

Specifically I'm having trouble finding the upperbounds for $x$ and $y$. Do I need to manipulate the $z$ inequality to get bounds for the inner integrands?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Mathematical expressions should be formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

First step z limits (obvious) $[x+y,4-x-y]$.   To get the $x$ and $y$ limits, use the inequality around z to get $x+y\le 4-x-y$ or $x+y\le 2$.  You can integrate $x$ or $y$ first.  For $y$ first, the integration is over $[0,2-x]$ and the $x$ range is $[0,2]$

To summarize $\int_9^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_{x+y}^{4-x-y}xdV$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we have $x,y\ge 0$. Then also $x+y\le 4-(x+y)$, thus $x+y\le 2$. So we can write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\iiint_U x\; dx\; dy\; dz
&=
\int_{x\in [0,2]}
x
\int_{y\in [0,2-x]}
\int_{z\in [x+y,4-x-y]}
dx\; dy\; dz
\\
&=
\int_{x\in [0,2]}
x\int_{y\in [0,2-x]}
((4-x-y)-(x+y))\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x\in [0,2]}
x
\int_{y\in [0,2-x]}
(4 -2x-2y)\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_{x\in [0,2]}
x\Big[\ -(2-x-y)^2\ \Big]_{y=0}^{y=2-x}
\; dx
\\
&=
\int_{x\in [0,2]}
x\cdot(2-x)^2
\; dx
\\
&\qquad\text{and we could have jumped directly here,}
\\
&\qquad\text{since for a fixed $x$ the possible values of $(y,z)$ are in a square,}
\\
&\qquad\text{the side of square being linear in $x$}
\\
&=\int_0^2 x(2-x)^2\; dx=\int_0^2 x^2(2-x)\; dx
=\left[\frac 23x^3-\frac 14 x^4\right]_0^2
\\
&=16\left(\frac 13-\frac 14\right)=16\cdot\frac 1{12}=\frac 43\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer check, here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: var('x,y,z');
sage: integral( integral( integral( x, (z,x+y,4-x-y) ), (y,0,2-x) ), (x,0,2) )
4/3
```